# Get text properties from Flow Document

Tags: c#, wpf

How can we get `text` properties like `bold`, `italic`, `text alignment`, etc. from a `Flow Document` (in a `RichTextBox` control)? Can we get these properties in a single `TextRange` or `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Simpler than I thought.

My solution is to go word by word (or Textpointer) and get the TextRange.GetPropertyValue.

TextElement and Inline Dependency Property has everything I need. FontWeight, FontStyle, BaseAalignment, etc, I just had to play a little bit with my code until I got what I needed

Hope it helps someone :-)